# Google Maps Lists only visible in Web Version not in Mobile App (Mac/Apple)

Tags: ios, google-maps

after switching to a new iPhone (11 max pro), all my lists with saved places are gone on my phone but they are still there in my Google account when I access maps via Web.
On top of that, the minute I create a NEW list on my phone, then close and open the app, the list is gone again. But it is there on when I access google maps via a computer.

Only things I can save are "Favorits" "Want to go", "Label", "Marked sopts", "Travel plans" but no lists.

Can anyone help?:-)

Answer (score 0):

In Google Maps for iOS, the 'lists' are available under the 'saved' tab at the bottom. You may need to scroll down a bit though.

[image: The main screen of Google Maps, with the Saved tab highlighted]
[image: The 'Saved' tab of Google Maps, with 'Your Lists' highlighted]